# Inner Product and Norm question

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s69lI.png)

I am currently stuck on finding the norm for U. It is either sqrt(66) or sqrt(171). I think. When I am trying to find the norm in the question I am required to use the inner product correct?

Comment: It's $\sqrt{171}$, you are supposed to use the non-standard inner product given in the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you fro the feedback. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

We have $||u||^2=2 \cdot 16+2 \cdot 9+25+6 \cdot 16=171.$

Comment: Nice to see I am on the right track somewhere.